# Dynamically validate allowed entity values in Dialog Flow

Tags: dialogflow-es

In my Dialog Flow agent, I have an entity `@city`. Possible values are `New York`, `Berlin`, ... But `Amsterdam` is not in that list.

Is there a way to dynamically validate an entity value against the values in my SQL database? For example, if the user writes `Amsterdam`, I want to give the user an hint that he should ask for another city. Can this be done via a webhook?

Or should I synchronize my database cities with the agent on a regular basis? If so, can this be done via an API?

I am not sure what the standard way of this is here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options here, depending on what will work best for you.

In the most simple case you can set the parameter entity type to `@sys.any` and handle all the name resolution in your webhook. This is the worst possible scenario.

As you've done, you can create your own entity type, `@city`, and populate it with a few cities. If you want to populate it with the cities in your database, there *is* an API (hence the old name, API.AI) that lets you create and modify Entities. See the documentation at https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities for details.

Even best, however, might be a combination of the two. You have an Intent that uses `@city`, and another lower priority Intent that uses `@sys.any` (or a fallback intent) that handles the case of them saying something you don't understand.

Comment: Interesting! I'll experiment with populating the entity values via the API.